# Draw lines of a rectangle with raphael

Tags: raphael, draw, rectangles

I want to draw to lines of a rectangle in a animation.

this is what i got:

```
    window.onload = function() {  
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('ornament2'), 520, 520);

        var balk1 = paper.path("M10 10").animate({path: "M10 10 L510 10"}, 1000, function() {
            paper.path("M510 10").animate({path: "M510 10 L510 14"}, 80, function(){
                paper.path("M510 14").animate({path: "M510 14 L10 14"}, 1000, function(){
                    paper.path("M10 14").animate({path: "M10 14 L10 10"}, 80);
                });
            });
        }); 
      }
```

The rectangle is drawn, but if you look closely the cornes of the rectangle are not really closed.

Take a look at this example:

```
var balk2 = paper.path ("M10 256 L510 256 L510 260 L10 260 z");
```

If you make a rectangle this way, then the corners are sharp.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, @user1386906 -- why are you using a combination of paths instead of an actual rectangle primitive?

Comment: Because i want to animate the lines of the rectangle like its drawn on the canvas. I dont know if that is possible with the rectangle primitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED to apologize for previous idiocy:

I typically use a utility function like the following to draw arbitrary paths over a given duration of time:

```
function drawpath( canvas, pathstr, duration, attr, callback )
{
    var guide_path = canvas.path( pathstr ).attr( { stroke: "none", fill: "none" } );
    var path = canvas.path( guide_path.getSubpath( 0, 1 ) ).attr( attr );
    var total_length = guide_path.getTotalLength( guide_path );
    var last_point = guide_path.getPointAtLength( 0 );
    var start_time = new Date().getTime();
    var interval_length = 25;
    var result = path;       

    var interval_id = setInterval( function()
    {
        var elapsed_time = new Date().getTime() - start_time;
        var this_length = elapsed_time / duration * total_length;
        var subpathstr = guide_path.getSubpath( 0, this_length );            
        attr.path = subpathstr;
        path.animate( attr, interval_length );                         
        if ( elapsed_time >= duration )
        {
            clearInterval( interval_id );
            if ( callback != undefined ) callback();
        }                                       
    }, interval_length );  
    return result;
}
```

In this case, you'd simply call

```
var rectPath = drawpath( paper, "M10 10 L510 10 L510 14 L10 14 z", 4000, function()
    {
        // want to apply some other attributes to the finished rectangular path?  Here's where you'd do it.
    } );
```

This has the advantage of working with all sorts of complicated shapes, include textual paths if you're using `print`.  That means you can accomplish moderately more impressive drawing effects, like [this](http://voidblossom.com/tests/pathTransform.php).

Comment: thank you for your help, but like i said i want to draw the lines of the rectangle one by one. The only i know how to do that is using  element.path

Comment: My apologies for being a nitwit, user1386906.

Comment: woww! Thank you so much. This saves me a lot of time! don't apologize, i appreciate all the help!

Comment: Gratzi.  Glad you both like it =)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to fix original, but maybe you can delete original and then redraw using one path

http://jsfiddle.net/XhHgs/1/

```
   window.onload = function() {  
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('ornament2'), 520, 520);

        var balk1 = paper.path("M10 10").animate({path: "M10 10 L510 10"}, 1000, function() {
                var path2=paper.path("M510 10");
                path2.animate({path: "M510 10 L510 14"}, 80, function(){
                var path3 = paper.path("M510 14");
                path3.animate({path: "M510 14 L10 14"}, 1000, function(){
                    paper.path("M10 14").animate({path: "M10 14 L10 10"}, 80).remove();
                    path3.remove();
                    path2.remove();
                    balk1.remove();
                    balk1  = paper.path ("M10 10 L510 10 L510 14 L10 14 z");
                });
            });
        }); 
      }​
```

EDIT

on the second thought just use this

http://jsfiddle.net/XhHgs/3/

```
   window.onload = function() {  
        var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('ornament2'), 520, 520);

        var balk1 = paper.path("M10 10").animate({path: "M10 10 L510 10"}, 1000, function() {
                balk1 .animate({path: "M10 10 L510 10 L510 14"}, 80, function(){
                  balk1 .animate({path: "M10 10 L510 10 L510 14 L10 14"}, 1000, function(){
                   balk1.animate({path: "M10 10 L510 10 L510 14 L10 14 z"}, 80);
                });
            });
        }); 
      }​
```